# How to deal with FK in views

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am working with MVC and I have a question regarding FK in views. For example, I have a User model and a Data model. The Data has a FK to the User. On the Edit View of the DataController, I get the Id of the User from the URL, which works perfectly. This happens in several views/controllers I am working on.

But I think it is quite a repetitive procedure to check if the Model Id exists every single time I work on a Controller with FK. Just as an example of the usual procedure:

```
var db = new MyContext();

var user = db.Users.Find(Id);

// verify if user exists
if (user == null )
{
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}

// verify if model is valid
if(!ModelState.IsValid)
{
     model.User = user
     return View(model)
}
```

The example above is just a short example of something that happens all over and over again in my code. I have to check validity of things several times. Is this usual? Also, my EditDataViewModel has a User field, and if the Model is not valid I have to set again the model.User to user. When I have several references I have to reset them several times.

I tried to use the code

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.User)
```

And it does not work the intended way. On my controller the received model.User is null.

Could sombody point me out if I am doing it the usual way or if there is a more beautiful way of doing it?

Comment: Your cannot bind a form control to a complex object which is why `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.User)` fails. Why do you need to keep getting the user? All you should really need is the users ID property

Comment: I know I only need the users ID, but technically, I should not access the data layer on my view, right? So if I write the following code `db.Users.Find(Model.UserId)` on my View to get the user's data, I would be doing it wrong, wouldn't I?

Comment: Why would you need to do that in the view? You need to provide a bit mote code to understand what your trying to do and display/edit in your view.

Comment: I just want to display some specific information of the User in the Edit View of my Data. If my EditDataViewModel only contains my user's Id I won't be able to do so, therefore I also have a User field in my ViewModel

Comment: Not necessarily. You can use a `UserVM` in your `EditDataViewModel` where `UserVM` contains only those properties you need to display/edit and then you can use hidden fields for each property of `UserVM`